# Windows 11 search box doesn't appear

Tags: windows, search, taskbar, windows-11

I just updated to Win11 on one of my PCs. Only on this PC, the taskbar "search" magnifying glass doesn't pull up the search box (it turns colors to indicate it's active but no search window appears) and if I click the Windows taskbar icon and start typing, or click in the search field in that popup window, the popup just disappears and doesn't bring up the search box.

On my other Windows machine everything is fine. What did I do wrong & how can I fix it? (Yes, I've restarted, updated to latest, and restarted Windows search service).

I do notice the Windows Search Indexer taking a fair amount of CPU and I/O. I checked the administrative logs, don't see anything interesting.

Comment: Do you have any third-party applications designed to modify the start menu by chance?

Comment: Good question, but no, just using stock start menu.

Comment: Have you tried restarting SearchHost.exe and/or the Windows Search service?

Comment: Yes, did both of those. No change.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what fixed it; maybe it was playing with taskbar settings, but it's working now. You don't know how much you count on that search til it's gone! Gotta love Windows.